# Hanging indent for python output

Tags: python, string, format

I am trying to print some data in the following format:

```
Data 1: Foo1
        Foo2
        Foo3

Data 2: Stuff1
        Stuff2
        Stuff3
```

Currently, I have a variable tracking the data set, and the contents of each data set in a list. Intuitively, it seems like I should be able to simply do:

```
print("Data " + str(data_num) + ": ", end = "")
for d in dataset:
  print(d.rjust(len(d) + 8)
```

The problem is that this indents past the data label and gives me

```
Data 1:         Foo1
        Foo2
        Foo3
...
```

My current solution is to simply write

```
print(*dataset, sep = "\n        ")
```

in place of the for loop. This technically gives me the output I'm looking for, but it seems like there should be a much more satisfying solution than simply manually adding spaces.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: instead of spaces just use a \t for a tab?

Comment: you want like Data 1: Foo1 Foo2  Foo3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print("Data " + str(data_num) + ": ", end = "")
for k, d in enumerate(dataset):
    print(''.join(['\t\t' if k else '', d]))
```

It will add 8 spaces for each line except the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset = [['Foo1', 'Foo2', 'Foo3'], ['Foo1', 'Foo2', 'Foo3']]

for _ in xrange(len(dataset)):
    print("Data " + str(_ + 1) + ":"),
    append_tab = False
    for d in dataset[_]:
        if append_tab:
            result = "\t" + d
        else:
            result = d
            append_tab = True
        print (result)
```

You can use **/t** (tab) as an alternative and simpler solution.